# Magento - Creating new Adminhtml Form, but saveAction() not working

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and currently i'm working on a custom Magento extension!

Here is a screenshot of the Form:

[image]

When i hit `Save Item` i got this:

[image]

As you can see the `saveAction()` has not saved the changes.

When i place: `Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getPost());` to see if the form is working i get this:

```
2015-02-17T13:25:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [form_key] => zj9E8FpNOCyFIqaT
    [Receiver] => Veni
    [Phone] => 359884685063
    [Date] => 2015-02-05 19:06:44
)
```

By this i think the form is okey.

Let me show you all the code i have in my Extension!

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container


{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_status';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item Manager');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Add Item');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Grid.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('smsnotification_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }


    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smsnotification/smsnotification_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }


    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
          $this->addColumn('id', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('ID'),
              'align'     =>'right',
              'width'     => '50px',
              'index'     => 'id',
          ));

          $this->addColumn('Receiver', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
              'align'     =>'left',
              'index'     => 'Receiver',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('Phone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'Phone',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Date', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'Date',

        ));


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId()));
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Edit.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container

{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_status';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Save Item'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Delete Item'));
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('smsnotification_data') && Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getId() ) {
            return Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__("Edit Item '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getReceiver()));
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Add Item');
        }
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Edit/Form.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    {


        protected function _prepareForm()
            {
            $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                                    'method' => 'post',
                                 ));

                $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('edit_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item information')));

                $fieldset->addField('Receiver', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Receiver',
                     ));

                $fieldset->addField('Phone', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Phone',
                    ));

                $fieldset->addField('Date', 'text', array(
                    'label'     => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
                    'class'     => 'required-entry',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'name'      => 'Date',
                    ));

                if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getsmsnotificationData() )
                    {
                        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getsmsnotificationData());
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData(null);
                    } elseif ( Mage::registry('smsnotification_data') ) {
                        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('smsnotification_data')->getData());
                    }
                // Add these two lines


                $form->setUseContainer(true);
                $this->setForm($form);

                ////

                return parent::_prepareForm();
            }
    }
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/controllers/Adminhtml/SmsorderstatusesController.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml_SmsorderstatusesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('SMS Center'))->_title($this->__('SMS Center'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('vivassms');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $smsnotificationId     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $smsnotificationModel  = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification')->load($smsnotificationId);

        if ($smsnotificationModel->getId() || $smsnotificationId == 0) {

            Mage::register('smsnotification_data', $smsnotificationModel);

            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_setActiveMenu('vivassms');

            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));
            $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item News'));

            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status_edit'));

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Item does not exist'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            try {
                Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

                $smsnotificationModel->setReceiver($postData['Receiver'])
                ->setPhone($postData['Phone'])
                ->setDate($postData['Date'])
                ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData(false);

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setsmsnotificationData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }

        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
            try {
                $smsnotificationModel = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification');

                $smsnotificationModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->delete();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
    /**
     * Product grid for AJAX request.
     * Sort and filter result for example.
     */
    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
               $this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_smsnotification_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <smsnotification>
                <file>smsnotification.xml</file>
            </smsnotification>
        </updates>
    </layout>   
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Resource/Smsnotification.php:

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource_Smsnotification extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification','id');
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/Resource/Smsnotification/Collection.php:

```
<?php 
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource_Smsnotification_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification');    
    }
}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Model/

```
<?php
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Smsnotification extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('smsnotification/smsnotification');
    }

}
```

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/sql/smsnotification_setup/install-1.0.0.php:

```
<?php
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Receiver` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
    ");
$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

This are all files which i have in my Extension, exept adminhtml.xml and system.xml.
If you think they are important to be shown i'll show them.

So do you can you see the problem why it is not making the save properly ?
Can you help me out fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the id is missing in the post data. So it doesn't load the needed model data but creates a new entry.
Probably,  `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')` returns null.

Add a hidden field `id` to you form with the entry id.

Comment: So if i create `Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));` it should return null in my log file if your guess is correct ?

Comment: Yes. If so, just add a hidden field with the id as in JonaPk's example below.

Comment: @TonyStark, regarding the db, it doesn't matter in this case, imho.
If you added this field, make sure in the html source code that it's value has been populated from the model and it is being sent in POST to your controller.

Comment: How can i check does it send it to the controller ?

Comment: 1. Use debugger
2. Make `print_r($_POST)` in controller.

Answer (score 0):

xpoback is correct, you need to add an hidden field in your form if you're in edit action:

So in _prepareForm(), add before the Receiver field:

```
$model = Mage::registry('smsnotification_data');
if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'id',
            ));
        }
```

Comment: I think this maybe is not the problem. Take a look at the form file after your suggest: http://pastebin.com/fXrS3ja4 And still it is not making the changes. Also take a look at this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57473/creating-new-adminhtml-form-but-saveaction-not-working/57475#57475 Do you think this can be a problem too ?

Comment: Yes it can be a problem too...
You shoud always write db ralted thing in lowercase (field names, table names, ...) because Magento ORM do transformations from underscores to camelcase and vice-versa... So it can be a problem, and moreover it's diffiult to debug

Comment: So you suggest me to change the table name from `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` to `vivasindustries_smsnotification` and all the table row names ?

Comment: No it's not necessary since for the table name, magento will look inside your config.xml but, you should do it systematically, it's a convention to follow (best practices) but for the field names, yes you should do it...

Comment: I've made that and i get this error when i try to submit the changes by hitting `Save Item` -> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (id='13')' at line 1` Can you give me any advice about this ?

Comment: You really need to triple-check all form field names, just to be sure (and to do the thing right...)...
Put all in lowercase, in DB field names, in form field names... And do this: $smsnotificationModel->setData($postData)->save(); in your controller saveAction(). If all fields are correctly "mapped" (so their names are the same everywhere and Magento can use his magic methods) it should just work... So it's a lot of comments here... we will need to move in a chat soon if it continues